# How to print file name with data from where data is coming?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have below mentioned files in path 1,

```
fb1.tril.cap
fb2.tril.cap
fb3.tril.cap
```

For example data in file fb1.tril.cap are like shown below,

```
AT99565 150 500 (DEST 81) 
AT99565 101 501 (DEST 883) 
AT99565 152 502 (419)
```

For example data in file fb2.tril.cap are like shown below,

```
AT99565 103 1503 (DEST 165) 
AT99565 104 154  (DEST 199)
```

For example data in file fb3.tril.cap are like shown below,

```
RT61446 80 863 (DEST 968) 
RT20447 32 39 (DEST 570) 
RT51224 73 74 (592)
```

I had written code like shown below to print my required fields,

```
while read file_name
do
cat ${file_name} | awk -F' ' '$4 == "(DEST" { print 
$1, $2, $3, $5}' | awk -F')' '{print  $1, $2, $3, $4}' | uniq >> output.csv
done < path_1
```

I'm getting below output,

```
AT99565 150 500 81
AT99565 101 501 883
AT99565 103 1503 165
AT99565 104 154  199
RT61446 80 863 968
RT20447 32 39 570
```

But i want to print file name also along with data from where data is coming, like shown below,

```
AT99565 150 500 81 fb1.tril.cap
AT99565 101 501 883 fb1.tril.cap
AT99565 103 1503 165 fb2.tril.cap
AT99565 104 154  199 fb2.tril.cap
RT61446 80 863 968 fb3.tril.cap
RT20447 32 39 570 fb3.tril.cap
```

Can anyone help me to complete my job by printing file name as well along with the data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the logic to process your inputs? E.g. why  `AT99565 152 502` line should be removed?

Comment: This one awk -F' ' '$4 == "(DEST" { print 
$1, $2, $3, $5}' typo modified now.

Answer (score 0):

First I am not able to test my code solution but this code might be run for you.

```
while read file_name
do
cat ${file_name} | awk -F' ' '$5 == "(DEST" { print 
$1, $2, $3, $5}' | awk -F')' '{print  $1, $2, $3, $4, $file_name}' | uniq >> output.csv
done < path_1
```

Comment: I don't have working environment to run this code, But the above code might be ok.

Comment: It is not working, for example, i'm getting like this AT99565 150 500 81     AT99565 150 500 81) as one output row.

Comment: Try this code.................
while read file_name
do
cat ${file_name} | awk -F' ' '$5 == "(DEST" { print 
$1, $2, $3, $5}' | awk -F')' '{print  $1, $2, $3, $4, ${file_name}}' | uniq >> output.csv
done < path_1

Comment: I have edited answer "file_name" instead of  "file".

Comment: Still same error dev i.e, awk: {print  $1, $2, $3, $4, ${file_name}}
awk:                          ^ syntax error

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` one-liner:

```
sed 's/[()]\|DEST//g;F' fb*.tril.cap | sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n/ /gp'
```

How it works:

1. `s/[()]\|DEST//g`:  Instead of parsing `(DEST` and such, just remove them.  What's left after that are the four desired items.
2. Then use `sed`'s **`F`***ile name* command to print the file name.
3. Since `F` prints immediately, a 2nd `sed` invocation is needed to juggle the output a bit.

If the output spacing is too uneven, add a `tr` to convert the spaces into tabs:

```
sed 's/[()]\|DEST//g;F' fb*.tril.cap | sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n/ /gp' | 
tr -s ' '
```

Comment: I don't have rights to use sed command...can you give me another solution?

Comment: It sounds like your dealing with a restricted environment, so we need more information about what's restricted.  Please post the output of `echo ${SHELL}; uname -a; lsb_release -a`.  Also, can you run `awk` or `perl`? -- the other answers seem to imply those have sufficient permissions to work, which would be unusual if `sed` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one liner

```
> ls -l fb*tril*cap
-rw-r--r-- 1 aaaaa bbbbb 77 Dec  6 09:20 fb1.tril.cap
-rw-r--r-- 1 aaaaa bbbbb 58 Dec  6 09:21 fb2.tril.cap
-rw-r--r-- 1 aaaaa bbbbb 74 Dec  6 09:21 fb3.tril.cap
> perl -lane ' print $_,$ARGV if $F[3]=~/\(DEST/ and s/\(DEST //g and s/\)//g '  fb*tril*cap
AT99565 150 500 81 fb1.tril.cap
AT99565 101 501 883 fb1.tril.cap
AT99565 103 1503 165 fb2.tril.cap
AT99565 104 154  199 fb2.tril.cap
RT61446 80 863 968 fb3.tril.cap
RT20447 32 39 570 fb3.tril.cap
>
```